# Approaches to hide certain list columns from certain users groups, inside the add/edit/views form & inside list views without using 3rd party tools

Tags: 2013, list, development, permissions, form

I am creating a new list inside SharePoint server 2013,  which have these columns:-

1. Title
2. Description
3. Price
4. Other…

Now I want to only allow users within a specific group to be able to view and modify the price field inside these locations:-

1. View/edit/add forms.
2. Inside the list views.

So can anyone advice if SharePoint support this requirement, to hide list columns based on permissions? if there is not any option to do so , is there any workaround ? baring in mind that i am using on-premise SharePoint enterprise 2013 , and i have full access to the farm..

Answer (score 5):

Yes and yes.

You can hide the columns on the forms by adding custom action to each of the forms like this:

```
<CustomAction Id="Project.DisplayForm"
            Location="DisplayFormToolbar"
            ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
            ControlClass="Project.ProjectListFormCustomActions"
            RegistrationType="ContentType"
            RegistrationId="0x010020CA30C66D23475D926915EB818F52B905">
</CustomAction>
```

Alternatively, you can use `EditFormToolbar` and `NewFormToolbar`.

This will attach a custom action to the Display Form of a specified content type. What you do next is add a control class and override `OnLoad` function. There you check if the user is allowed to view the field by checking which group the current user is in. Then depending on that you hide the whole column row from the form:

```
namespace Project.CustomActions
{
    class ProjectListFormCustomActions : Control
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if (IsUserAllowedToViewTheField() == false)
            {
                HideControlRow(projectLinkField, "{E989D599-7476-4036-A1E8-2C5B8D334412}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you hide the row from the form like this:

```
private void HideControlRow(SPField field, String scriptId)
{
    if (field != null)
    {
        string controlId = field.InternalName;

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);

        text.AppendFormat("_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('Hide{0}ControlRow');", controlId);
        text.AppendFormat("function Hide{0}ControlRow()", controlId);
        text.AppendLine("{");
        text.AppendFormat("$('.ms-formtable td').each(function()");
        text.AppendLine("{");
        text.AppendFormat("var s = $(this).html();");
        text.AppendFormat("if(s.indexOf('{0}')!= -1)", controlId);
        text.AppendLine("{");
        text.AppendFormat("$(this).closest('tr').hide();");
        text.AppendLine("}})}");

        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(ProjectListFormCustomActions), scriptId, text.ToString(), true);
    }
}
```

I believe you can achieve the same thing using **Client Side Rendering** by setting `BaseFieldControl` properties in `SPContext.Current.FormContext.FieldControlCollection` (which is avaible from the custom action code-behind as well).

As for the views, what I would suggest is to have a library with the .aspx files and custom item permissions where you would allow one group of people to access one kind of views (with the price column) and another group of people (who are not price-worthy) would have access to view files without the column in them. And then have a page where users would click on the view links. Other people achieve this by using audience targeting feature:

> 1. Create view A, B, C for list TestList
> 2. Create user group X, Y, Z
> 3. Open the TestList, bu default all items will display in AllItems.aspx page
> 4. Edit the page by using Site Action
> 5. Click on the Modify Shared Web Part link of TestList . Now select the View A from selected dropdown
> 6. Go to Advanced section and select user group in the target audience. Apply the changes
> 7. Add the TestList web part again to the same AllItems.aspx page.
> 8. Repeat the step 5 and 6 for other two views and set the target audience respectively.
> 9. Now the AllItems.aspx page will have three web part for one list i.e TestList

To do a custom form validation, override the `OnSaveHandler` in the `OnInit` 
function in the custom action:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    SPContext.Current.FormContext.OnSaveHandler += new EventHandler(FormContext_OnSave);
}

protected void FormContext_OnSave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.Validate();

    if (DoesTheUserHavePermissionsToSave() == true) //This is where you check for user permissions
    {
        SaveButton.SaveItem(SPContext.Current, false, String.Empty);
    }
    else //the user doesn't have permissions to edit the price field
    {
        var list = SPContext.Current.List;
        var item = list.GetItemById(SPContext.Current.ListItem.Id);
        SPContext.Current.ListItem["Price"] = item["Price"]
        SaveButton.SaveItem(SPContext.Current, false, String.Empty);
        //this would need testing but the idea is to reassign previous Price value before saving the item.
        //Or check if the value has changed and cancel the save completely since there might be something other messed up as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,seems a lot of work, but at the same time seems promising approach to follow, i will spend some days to try this hopefully it will work for me

Comment: can you please adivce how i can implement the IsUserAllowedToViewTheField() function ?as inside the "ProjectListFormCustomActions " control i need to reference this function? can you advice on this please ?

Comment: It should be the place where you check if the user is allowed to view the field. I don't know exact requirements or AD/SP groups used. It might look something like this: var group = web.Groups["Specific Group"]; var isInTheGroup = web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(group .ID);

Comment: ok thanks again for the great help, you really placed me on the right path to achieve this.. but can you please adivce on the main differences between implementing this as a custom action on the view/add/edit forms ? or implementing it using client side rendering ? now i used JSLINK and client side rendering inside my application to hide some columns from the quick edit grid . but not sure how i can benefit from it to achieve my current requirements ?

Comment: I believe you could. CSR is hard typed - I personally prefer that but I don't think there are any disadvantages of using custom actions as you can achieve even more with them.

Comment: If i manage to add a custom action to the forms to hide the Price column from unauthorized users,, then will these unauthorized users be able to read or modify the Price value by hacking the system?As i am hiding the value from the forms, but i am not validating that when a user add/edit/view a list item, to check if the user is authorized to modify the Price field? I am from asp.net background and usually we check any custom authorizations when accepting the Post request on the server side,regardless if the field is being rendered inside the edit or create forms,did you get my point ?

Comment: can you please adivce on my previous comment , on whether hiding a filed from certain users using custom action on the add/edit/view forms , will guarantee that unauthorized users will not be able to view or modify the Price field in my case? as generally speaking client side validation (such as hiding a field from a form) can always be bypassed ,and this validation should be done on the server side also, to be sure that only authorized users can manage the Price field,,, not sure if the case inside SharePoint is different??

Comment: Just because the field is hidden on the form, doesn't mean the user can not modify those values. You can't lock down columns using JavaScript. Only server side code can do that.

Comment: Override the Save button: "SPContext.Current.FormContext.OnSaveHandler += new EventHandler(FormContext_OnSave);" with a custom function where you would validate the form or add an event receiver with an additional check - handle ItemAdding event and assign empty value to the price field or cancel the addition of the item if user doesn't have permissions. There are many ways to do that and I believe this is going off topic already :)

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis thanks for the reply. but i am not sure why you are saying that the question is going off topic.. my original question was about preventing certain users (based on their permissios) from viewing or modifying the Price field, and i was looking to to this in a secure manner,,not just depending on hiding the field from the html..

Comment: The title says "Approaches to hide certain list columns from certain users groups" and this might be misleading for other site users as they might find different things being discussed here than the title describes - as the form validation and etc.. Anyway, is the Save button override or an event receiver will work for your needs or is there a need to explore more options?

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis now how i need to create the "FormContext_OnSave" ? should i create an event receiver for example,, can you adivce more on this please ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You do that in the custom action code-behind (ProjectListFormCustomActions cass file - same place where you hide the fields) . Override OnInit function and add a new OnSaveHandler.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis can you please recheck you edit ,, as i can not see the update (you answer is last modified on 29 feb)

Comment: I added that on 29th of Feb, just search for FormContext_OnSave on this page and you'll find it :) It's at the end of the answer. Follow these steps and you'll override the default Save button functionality.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis so let me recap your answer.. now i need to create a server side event receiver for my list ? and inside the server side event receiver i will override the FormContext_OnSave  ? is this correct? this will prevent users from modifying the field when they add/edit an item inside the list .. second point ,, now how i can hide the field using javascript is using jslink an approach to follow? third point , if i manage to implement the above 2 points,, so i am preventing users from viewing the field using client side rendering and preventing them from modifying the value using server

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis side checking,,, so the only thing left is how to prevent users from viewing the field using server side techniques ?

Comment: John,you don't need an event receiver for that.What you need is:1.A custom action attached to a list or a content type with a specified control class.This control class will be called every time a user accesses a list/item/form (wherever the custom action is).2.In the OnLoad method of that control class you hide the columns (see HideControlRow).3.In the OnInit method of the same control class you override the save functionality.4.You would be hiding columns with JS and validating the form with a custom save behavior (server side code). If you don't want JS, take a look at "SharePoint 2013 CSR"

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis so when i add a new custom action to my list or content type , then this custom action will make sure that the Price field will never be shown inside the list forms and inside the list views for unauthorized users??? is this correct ? and also if users try to edit this field , either using standard list forms or by trying to hack the system , then the custom action will prevent them from doing so?? can you adivce please ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36518/discussion-between-paul-strupeikis-and-john-g).

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery and REST api to check permissions:

```
 var userID = _spPageContextInfo.userId, authorised = false, groupName = "Admin";
    $.when($.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getByName('" + groupName + "')/Users?$filter=Id eq " + userID,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    })).then(function (data) {
        if (data.d.results[0] != undefined) {
            authorised = true;
        }
        else {
        }
    }).done(function () {

                if (!authorised) {


                        $("input[id^='Complete'],input[id^='Strength'],input[id^='DevArea']").each(function () {
                            if ($(this).length) {
                                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                            }
                        });


                }

            });
```

Requirement1 : View/edit/add view --> this can controlled by permission levels. users with contribute permissions can still edit the content but cant change/add views.

Requirement2: this can controlled by Attaching a JSLink file to the fields
Example:

```
    (function () { 

    // jQuery library is required in this sample 
    // Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable 
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>')); 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var hiddenFiledContext = {}; 
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates = {};  
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates.OnPostRender = hiddenFiledOnPreRender; 
    hiddenFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Age field on New and Edit forms 
        "Predecessors": { 
            "NewForm": hiddenFiledTemplate, 
            "EditForm": hiddenFiledTemplate,
             "View":hiddenFiledTemplate 
        } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(hiddenFiledContext); 

})(); 


// This function provides the rendering logic 
function hiddenFiledTemplate() { 
    return "<span class='csrHiddenField'></span>"; 
} 

// This function provides the rendering logic 
function hiddenFiledOnPreRender(ctx) { 
    jQuery(".csrHiddenField").closest("tr").hide(); 
}
```

Reference: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-a52cf8a7

Comment: I think you misunderstood my whole question , I am not asking how to prevent users from adding list views,, also your jslink will always hide the field from the view/add/edit forms,, while my question is how i can hide certain field/s from list forms and list views based on users permission (security group )... can you read my question again?

Comment: Ofcourse you want to hide them for selective users - this is an example which you can extend to your needs. I have added option 2 which uses SharePoint REST api to check if a users is in a group and applies html modifications accordingly. extend it according to your needs.

Comment: but what will be the differences between using Rest API and using custom actions on the view/add/edit forms ?

Comment: Reason1 : Server side object model is not the current best practice for SharePoint development. REST API is simple to use and very powerful

Comment: But if i hide the Price field using REST API (i will be mainly hiding the HTML from the forms, and i will not be doing any server side validation),, then i am not checking on the server side if the user is authorized to view/add/edit the Price value.. i mean if i manage to hide the Price value from the edit/add/view forms using REST API , will the user be able to bypass the client side rendering, and modify/view the Price value?

Comment: can you please adivce on my previous comment , on whether hiding a filed from certain users using Rest API will guarantee that  unauthorized users will not be able to view or modify the Price field in my case? as generally speaking client side validation can always be bypassed , not sure if the case inside SharePoint is different??

Comment: Just because the field is hidden on the form, doesn't mean the user can not modify those values. You can't lock down columns using JavaScript. Only server side code can do that.

Comment: @iOnline247 i already know this,, so what will be the approaches to prevent viewing or modifying the Price field by certain users  ?

Comment: You'll want to look into Event Receivers for preventing data manipulation.

http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/640

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not have the ability to apply permissions to a column.  There are third-party tools that claim to be able to do this; Google them if you want.

But I had these conceptual ideas that I haven't tried:

1. Have 2 separate lists with different permissions.  Use a workflow or event receiver to keep them in sync.  List A would have not have price, but list B would.  The workaround is to direct the two different user groups to the correct list.  You could use a link list with item level permissions for this.
2. Set the column as hidden to remove the column from forms.  Turn off datasheet view. Remove the column from all but 1 view that has inline editing enabled.  Finally, use audiences to allow that view to be displayed to your select few. -edit: may also need to disallow personal views

Comment: i was thinking if this can be achieved using the following approaches; to add a JSLINK to my field and to hide it from forms and list views based on users' permissions... this will make sure that users will not see the field,, now using JSLINK will not prevent users from hacking the system and get the value ,, is this correct ?so now i need a way to do a server-side checking to prevent unauthorized users from view/add/edit the field value ?is this possible?

Comment: Feel free to correct me, your primary motivation is to have 1 list in 1 location.  That is an admirable goal.  But SharePoint is intended to work together on information, not create divisions.  Users won't need to 'hack' your system; the contents will be searchable.  Depending on the security and the motivation of your users, this may be an acceptable risk for internal company use.  I don't use JS in random places of production as that would be an administrative nightmare.  This path may be possible, but I cannot guide you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to hide fields (due to access permissions or business logic), I prefer the following approach:

1) Hide the field programmatically

2) Develop a custom edit form

Both with **Server Object Model**.

**1) Hide the field programmatically**

A first option is to hide the field so that it is not seen anywhere. Even in the configuration of the list

```
Hidden = true;
```

Another is hiding on each form

```
ShowInNewForm = true;
ShowInEditForm = true;
ShowInDisplayForm = true;
```

**2) Develop a custom edit form**

Create an ASPX page that allows editing the item. In these screens you can:
- Hide information based on access permissions
- Disable information according to the state of the item or the business logic

In general I try to keep the standard new formSharePoint. But hidden many fields with ShowInNewForm option.

I hope you find it useful!

Comment: i did not get your point exactly,,, now if i define the options such as showInNewForm = true this will be applied to all users regardless of their permission .. is this correct ? i am not asking how to hide a field from the display form,, i am asking how to show/hide columns based on users permission !!

Comment: In this case I would use the "Hidden" option to hide fields and then develop custom forms and views. The field will not appear on standard forms (views, forms and even the configuration of the list). But you can display it in the customs screens, based on the user profile. It is expensive to implement.