# SP13: Form Column Permissions

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, content-type, custom-list

Is there a way using SharePoint 2013 to allow ALL users to see the column, but only allow other individuals to be able to make edits.  I know that I can change the permissions to "view only".  But there are instances when they should be able to edit other columns on the form.

I was thinking this could be achieved by creating a content type and changing the permissions.  This may not be the best route.  Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You cannot do that out-of-the-box. Take a look at this thread - there was an extensive discussion on this - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172196/approaches-to-hide-certain-list-columns-from-certain-users-groups-inside-the-ad . It might be too expensive to implement, tho.

Comment: Thanks @PaulStrupeikis.  Can you move your comment to the answer section?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that out-of-the-box. Take a look at this thread - there was an extensive discussion on this -[Approaches to hide certain list columns from certain users groups, inside the add/edit/views form & inside list views without using 3rd party tools](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172196/approaches-to-hide-certain-list-columns-from-certain-users-groups-inside-the-ad). It might be too expensive to implement, tho.